# Solving a nonlinear problem with a very small components with finite element method

Tags: finite-element, nonlinear-equations, iterative-method

In solving nonlinear hyperelastic solid mechanics problems, to converge to the correct solution we need to do step-by-step loading which makes the deformation at each step very small (for my particular problem $\mathcal{O}(e^{-11})$). Moreover, due to the material properties, the nonlinear weak form and consequently the linear system that should be solved at each step of the nonlinear solver have very small components. In my experience, this makes the iterative solvers very inefficient especially considering that many components are close to machine epsilon precision and the relative norm is too small and is not a good measure for the convergence. I would appreciate if you can help me to know

1) is what I am observing true or I am making a mistake somewhere?

2) what is the smart way to deal with such matrices that the weak form and consequently the resulted linear system have very small components?

What I am doing now to solve this nonlinear system is to reduce the absolute convergence norm criteria to a very small number $\mathcal{O}(e^{-13})$ when the absolute norm for 0 iteration is $\mathcal{O}(e^{-9})$. And use a relatively small relaxation value.

Thank you, everybody, for your help.

Comment: If you are having numerical problems because the solution is too close to machine epsilon, just change the units in your problem (e.g. meters to mm).

Comment: "Small" by itself is not a useful statement. Like Bill already says, if you measure distances in lightyears, then everything looks small. If you measure them in atomic units, then everything looks large. But the problem is still the same, and good solvers will solve the problem in the same number of iterations regardless of the units you choose. So when you say `1e-13`, then my question is `1e-13` what? `1e-13` lightyears?

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. For now, please just forget about physics. If I was able to fix the problem by just changing the units I would definitely do that. Just assume that we have a nonlinear weak form F(u,u') = 0 with very small components that I want to solve. What should I do?

Comment: @user2348209 "very small components that I want to solve" small with respect to what? Are you trying to solve a dimensionless system?

Comment: @user2348209: You totally misunderstood what I was trying to get at :-) "Machine precision" is not 1e-16. In floating point arithmetic, you can represent numbers down to 1e-308. Machine precision is always *relative*. If your matrix has entries that are all of size 1e-100, and your right hand side has entries of size 1e-100, then your solution will have entries of size 1 *and that's alright*. The problem only happens if you have entries of size 1 *and* of size 1e-100 in the same matrix or vector.

Comment: What do you mean with " the relative norm is too small and is not a good measure for the convergence"?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth thank you for taking the time and replying back. Sorry, if I misunderstood your point. Let me explain a bit more, maybe it helps to get better advice. In my nonlinear hyperelastic deformation problem, the ultimate deformation is large (about 20% to 30% of the domain length) so we are far from the solution at the beginning, and so the matrix components (jacobian of the weak form) and RHS are not in the same order and are hugely different. By step-by-step loading, both are getting closer but not completely solve the issue.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni by sating that I meant the relative norm is too small at the beginning iterations and remains small in the next iterations even though the absolute norms can be reduced up to 3 order of magnitude.

Comment: What is it that you call "relative norm"? Relative residual norm? What is your stopping criterion? Why is it "too small"? Could you report some numbers?

Comment: @user2348209: There is no reason why the matrix and rhs entries should be of the same magnitude. They have different physical units: if you have $Ax=b$ and $x$ denotes displacements, then the units of $A$ are the units of $b$ divided by length. That means, as mentioned before, that you can make the relative magnitudes of $A$ and $b$ whatever you want, by simply choosing different units for length.